# Использование притяжательных прилагательных, образованных от иностранных имен

Tags: словообразование

Для обозначения принадлежности предмета человеку можно использовать родительный падеж либо притяжательное прилагательное: совет отца — отцовский совет.

То же самое действует и для русских имён: сапоги Никиты — Никитины сапоги. Последнее при этом на слух кажется устаревшим.

Однако с иностранными именами ситуация несколько другая: если сказать "яблоко Джона" мы можем, то "Джоново яблоко" сказать язык не поворачивается с аргументом "так не говорят".

Вместе с этим для географических названий и устоявшихся фраз притяжательные прилагательные, образованные от иностранных имен, используются свободно: Баренцово море, Эйфелева башня, Мафусаилов век, Архимедов винт.

Есть ли какие-то формальные правила? Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше при образовании притяжательных прилагательных могли выступать **нерусские фамилии  исторических деятелей** (марксова теория, шекспирова трагедия). 
  Однако  в современном языке наблюдается **специализация суффикса ОВ**, который стал использоваться преимущественно **для образования русских фамилий** от сущ. м.р. (Акулов, Виноградов, Перов), и заметное ограничение его роли в образовании притяжательных прилагательных.

Даже прилагательные вида учителев, приятелев, генералов, конюхов, стариков, образованные от **нарицательных** существительных,  в большей степени используются  не в нейтральной, а в народной или просторечной речи.

Поэтому выражение "Джоново яблоко" совсем не характерно для русского языка.

Что касается **суффикса ИН,** то он используется преимущественно для образования притяжательных прилагательных от **сущ. ж.р.** (и м.р на А/Я): Танин, Сашин, Петин, дядин, тетин.

При этом важно учитывать, от какой основы нужно образовать прилагательное. Возможно, притяжательное прилагательное "Никитин" похоже на фамилию, поэтому кажется странным на слух.

(При ответе использованы материалы из  словаря Ефремовой).

Answer (score 0):

В художественных произведениях я встречаю притяжательные прилагательные, использованные от иностранных имен, и это смотрится вполне естественно. Я думаю, это зависит от стиля повествования: если есть желание приблизиться к разговорному, непринужденному стилю, то можно использовать подобный прием, если же речь идет об официальном стиле -- то не стоит так делать.

Answer (score 0):

Sergey Averyanov:

> *Однако с иностранными именами ситуация несколько другая: если сказать "яблоко Джона" мы можем, то "Джоново яблоко" сказать язык не
>   поворачивается с аргументом "так не говорят".*

Не верю в то, что Ваш язык, Сергей, споткнётся на, к примеру, этих строках из Ходасевича:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из одного из ответов в этой теме:

> *...выражение "Джоново яблоко" совсем не характерно для русского языка.*

Конечно, не характерно. Как и имя *Джон*...

Comment: Исключения всегда найдутся, особенно в поэтической речи.  В словаре же обозначена общая тенденция и объяснено наличие определенного количества притяжательных прилагательных, образованных от иностранных имен преимущественно исторических деятелей. Раньше этот суффикс был продуктивным,  теперь стал недостаточно продуктивным, то есть в меньшей степени служит образцом для образования новых слов. Кроме того, он перестал быть стилистически нейтральным.

Comment: Sergey, я о другом… Прочтите название темы: 
_Использование притяжательных прилагательных, образованных от иностранных имен._ 
**От иностранных…** Так вот я считаю, что суффикс _**-ов**_ что в прилагательных, образованных от иностранных имён, что в прилагательных, образованных от русских имён, одинаково правомерен (или неправомерен). И если нам с Вами (или кому-либо ещё) режет слух сочетание _"Джоново яблоко"_, то стоит спросить себя, а с каким из русских имён это яблоко сочетается лучше: _Федотово яблоко? Павлово яблоко?.._

Comment: -> По-моему, и эти варианты отдают какой-то искусственностью.  Так, может, дело вовсе не в  иностранных именах?

Comment: От русских имен суффикс ОВ образует фамилии, это его основная специализация, но стал реже использоваться для образования притяжательных прилагательных (Федотово яблоко). От иностранных имен можно образовать только прилагательное (Джоново яблоко), но и в этой функции он тоже применяется мало. Мы нейтрально воспринимаем только  русские фамилии суффиксом ОВ. Кстати, это не мое оригинальное мнение, я только пересказываю содержание словарной статьи.